# Выпадающий список вверх

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Здравствуйте.

Пытаюсь сделать выпадающий список

**JS**:

```
function elementPosition(el)
{
  var pos = el.offset();
  var left = pos.left;
  var top = pos.top;
  return { top: top, left: left }
}

var list = jQuery('<ul />').attr('class', 'list-ul');

$.each(data, function (key, val) 
{
   list.append('<li class="list-li">' + val.Name + '</li>');
});

$("body").append(list);
$(".list-ul").offset(elementPosition(element));
```

Этот код выполняется, когда придет ответ на ajax запрос. В результате выходит это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вот, как сделать, что бы он открывался вверх, а не в низ. Как бы, инвертировать его.

**CSS**:

```
.list-ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    max-height:400px;
    min-width:250px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    width:auto;
    position:absolute;
    padding:0;
    border:1px solid #eee;
}
.list-li:hover {
    background-color: #5199DB;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.li-active{
    background-color:#5199DB;
}
```

UPDATE как бы проблема решается установкой

```
 bottom:100%
```

но тогда высота становится нулевой

Comment: нужно изменить css для выпадающей части

Comment: Нам угадывать ваш DOM и стили? Зачем нам JS? Покажите стили и HTML

Comment: @Yuri, в данном случае js тоже нужен, так как положение рассчитывается с помощью него, а не css

Comment: что за функция _elementPosition_?

Comment: в  elementPosition  передается элемент то есть input под которым надо вывести список и  в ней расчитываются координаты вот CSS `.list-ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    max-height:400px;
    min-width:250px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    width:auto;
    position:absolute;
    padding:0;
    border:1px solid #eee;
}
.list-li:hover {
    background-color: #5199DB;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.li-active{
    background-color:#5199DB;
}`

Comment: @Санитариум, добавь ее реализацию. Раз ты хочешь изменить координаты вывода. очевидно нужно будет менять эту функцию

Comment: @Санитариум, вся необходимая информация должна быть непосредственно в вопросе. Отредактировать свой вопрос ты можешь нажав кнопку [edit] под ним